# Method navigateTo does not exist on type ComponentClass

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, typescript2.0

I use typescript and react, and I have the following call that does not work:

```
router.navigateTo(uri.path);
```

The router is a standard react component:

```
class Router extends React.Component < IRouterProps, any > {

  public constructor(props, context) {
     super(props, context);
  }

  public navigateTo(path: string) {
   (this.props as any).history.push(path);
  }
}
```

And the export is simple:

```
 let router = withRouter(Router) ;
 export default router;
```

Error that I get:

```
Property 'navigateTo' does not exist on type 'ComponentClass<Pick<any, never>>
```

I know that I can do `(router as any).navigateTo` and mitigate this. But I am wondering myself why does not work? It should work but I am clearly missing something.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

react-router [`withRoute` is typed as a generic](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b73b4426dd1cd78b7ddf4f4d1cc5b6316fd6956f/types/react-router/index.d.ts#L113). Component type should be provided as generic parameter:

```
 let router = withRouter<Router>(Router);
```